# How to publish a ROS topic with a delay?

Tags: ros

I am working with a simulation of a car and I see the road approximately 8 meter away from me and based on that, I steer the wheels. This steering signal (topic) **needs to have a 2 seconds delay** because my car moves very slowly.

I wonder if there is any command that can be used within ROS environment for helping me in implementation of that delay? If not what are your thoughts on how to add this delay? Thank you!

Comment: I kinda solved my problem in the following way:
I created a huge array where the steering angles are stored and my signal accessing this array with counter minus delay. Thus, not the actual steering value but with a certain delay...

But I understand that this method is unreliable and maybe someone knows if there is a better way!

Comment: this delay has to be in relation to what?

Comment: @ignacio to the current time

Comment: You have this array possibility. You could could create a thread and detach it to only send a message after the delay. (You don't want to have you callback stuck with a `sleep` method)
Have you also considered changin you steering/perception algorithm? What you are trying to achieve seems like a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce frequency of signal at which you are publishing.

> F = 1 / T = 1/ 2(sec) = 0.5Hz

Use these method to set frequency.

```
ros::Rate loop_rate(0.5);
loop_rate.sleep();
```